# Firefox doesn't always start up and "forgets" history

Tags: windows-7, firefox, history

I have a few issues with Firefox.

- Most of the time when I start Firefox, it doesn't do anything, the process does not show up either. Only when I open it for a second or third time, it actually opens.
- Firefox forgets my history, active sessions on websites, etc. even though I have set it to save it.

I have the latest version of Firefox, without add-ons, on W7

Comment: Assuming Windows?

Comment: Yes indeed, w7, I'll add it

Comment: Can you tell us which extensions you have, and as James Hopkins suggests below, does it start ok in Safe Mode?

Answer (score 0):

Right first things first, run any malware or anti-virus software that you have on the computer, because it sounds like you have a cookie causing problems, so running your anit-virus software could pick it up and then dispose of them.

Secondly you probably have a dodgy extension - kill firefox in processes then open firefox in safe mode (start>all programs>mozilla firefox>safe mode)

If it opens quickly, it points to an extension or toolbar, especially one loaded by security software.

To keep your system running smoothly, use CCleaner - make sure your browsers are closed when you run ccleaner
http://www.filehippo.com/download_cclean…

hope this information helps you in some shape or form